# Специализация метода шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть шаблонный класс:

```
template<typename Type>
class Node : public NodeBase {
    public:
        Node( QString name, NodeBase* parent ): NodeBase(name, parent) {}
       ~Node() {}

        // ... a lot of methods uses _data

        virtual QVariant data(int column, int role) const {
            // ...
        }

        virtual bool setData(int column, const QVariant &value, int role) {
            // ...
        }

    private:
        Type    _data;
}
```

Но хорошо было бы специализировать виртуальные функции data и setData для случая, когда `Type` - это `enum`. Как это можно сделать?

Я знаю как специализировать весь класс `Node` для случая `enum`, но тогда придется переписывать все остальные функции, которые используют `_data`.

Comment: В С++ нет частичной специализации шаблонов функций. Поэтому вот просто так в лоб специализировать методы для группы типов не получится. Для конкретного типа (явная специализация) специализировать отдельный метод проблемы нет, а вот частичная специализация в языке отсутствует.